# Overloaded functions in C++

Tags: c++

Are this functions overlaoded functions ?

```
void f(int a, int b) {}
void f(int& a, int& b) {}
void f(int* a, int* b) {}
void f(const int a, const int b) {}
```

Or overloading functions occurs only when the number or type of arguments differ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number 1, 2, 3 are. Number 4 redeclared number 1.

You see, top-level const-qualifiers don't affect the function declaration. They alter the way in which you use them inside a function definition, but it's still the same function

```
void f(int);
void f(const int); //redeclares
void f(const int x) //same as above
{
   x = 4; //error, x is const
}
```

This, on the other hand is fine

```
void f(const int); 
void f(int x) //same as above
{
   x = 4; //OK Now
}
```

Note that non-top-level consts do participate in overload resolution. E.g.

```
void f(int & x)
void f(const int & x) //another function, overloading the previous one
```

And finally, you are asking

> Or overloading functions occurs only
>   when the number or type of arguments
>   differ ?

Yes, that's right, but `int` , `int*`, and `int&` are different types. Of course, in case of 1 or 3, in most cases it will be ambiguous calls, but in some cases the compiler can tell which one you mean. For example

```
void f(int);
void f(int&);
f(3)//calls f(int)
int x = 3;
f(x); //ambiguous call;
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd would cause ambiguity!

Comment: I found in my notebook something that i marked a while ago while reading Thinking in C++, "if the diference between two functions is only that one has arguments pass by value and the other has arguments pass by reference, its not overloading", so I am a little confuse

Comment: @Armen: I meant with l-values the call would be ambiguous between 1st and 2nd function!

Comment: @vBx: That's bull excrement, so to say :) It is perfect overloading, and the overload resolution will choose the pass-by-value version if an rvalue is passed and will not be able to resolve ambiguity if lvalue is passed.

Comment: @Nawaz: Sure, but overloading and abmiguity are somewhat orthogonal. The question is whether the declarations redeclare the same funcion or declare a new one. It's another story how overload reolution chooses which function to call

Comment: @Armen: perhaps could you also cover exception specifications / storage qualifiers ? It may bloat the answer though...

Comment: @Matthieu: 1. It would bloat the answer 2. I cannot give a full specification of overloading in 1 answer 3. I am lazy. Bottom line: I don't feel like doing it right now :)

Comment: @Matthieu: But feel free to do it yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

Although 1st, and 2nd would cause ambiguity with lvalues, nevertheless they're overload. And 4th is redefinition of 1st:

http://ideone.com/lRFQi

Comment: Why not include output/code in stackoverflow? I see that ideone is a pastebin with special compilation/debugging abilities, but your link will presumably become invalid before this answer goes away.

Comment: 1 and 2 would only be ambiguous with r-values... or would this also apply to l-values ?

Comment: regarding all the answers i am confuse now, i think Thinkin in C++ states that if the difference between to functions is that one has arguments pass by value and the other pass by reference its not overloading. What about passing pointers ? My conclusion is that none are overloaded functions, am I correct ?

Comment: @Matthieu: It's the other way round.

Comment: @vBx: could you put the extract in your question, it seems highly dubious to me that such a glaring mistake would have been made.

Comment: @Matthieu: sorry i only have it on paper marked with red :) I know i was taking notes while reading that book, but  maybe i saw it somewhere else and noted, so i wont forget.